# Ruby/Slim: parse Markdown from a YAML file

Tags: ruby, parsing, markdown, slim-lang

Been struggling for a while with some YAML parsing inside a Slim template.

my YAML file contain

```
shortdesc: >
 markdown:
  if you want to up the feelgood factor Cuban style, then this Monday night at The Buffalo    Bar is for you...
```

But when I output the shortdesc node in my template it's displayed as a string and not interpreted. ("markdown: if you....")

Is there a way to parse the YAML output string to interpret the markdown code?
If I try

```
p
  markdown:
    = shortdesc
```

the template doesn't understand the call to the variable containing the YAML node.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the Markdown Library that you are using.

In BlueCloth, it would be something like this:

```
= BlueCloth.new(shortdesc).to_html
```

Comment: I'm currently using maruku, I'll check if there is something similar and your suggestion. cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. Just need to use interpolation:

```
p
  markdown:
    #{shortdesc}
```

Comment: I did try that but unsuccesfully, I will have another go when I get back home. Cheers

Comment: I tried again and i can't definitely make it work. even in I inline the markdown bit in a variable (@copy = "But can include **Markdown** using the [appropriate Haml](http://www.ptt.com 'testtest test') filter."). I should metion that I'm using serve-app, could it be the problem?